# Is it efficient to save game data and load all variables including lists from JSON into to a MYSQL database?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am intend to savegame save and load all the player data in json to mysql database using database unity with PHP. Is it effective ?.

My analysis that we don't need to use binary formatter to make a savegame file and if saving and convert the savegame data to mysql database our game can login and load continues play in any devices. We also have a big capacity i think in the disk.

If we save to database mysql we also don't need to used a transfer device feature to move to another devices if want to continues playing with the different mobile devices. All we need just login to database to get the savegame that store i Database Mysql.

Is this sense a problem with this way ? Like maybe making it lag or slowdown the game and soon.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the strong reply to your question is **it depends** on different things.
Two consideration according to my understanding with respect to your question,

1. If you want to maintain user score-board or access of user game data across different devices then you have to store data on server. No matter what are the loading/unloading time concerns

else

2. You can store it in user mobile like use [writing text file](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/how-to-write-a-file.8864/) or [PlayerPrefs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html)

You can also read [**Best Way to store data in Unity3d**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34426570/best-way-to-save-data-in-unity-game/34430383#34430383)

Comment: Hey @Mohammad, but i am not intend to use binary formater that writing text file because I think its got trouble when we use different devices to play and I think using PlayerPrefs also not effective in saving game because it take big data.

Comment: Hey @Mohammad, where i can find the tutorial save game using google play services savegame ? Thanks

Comment: Google Play services have a save game services. See this link : [link](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/savedgames) But i dont get how it work

Comment: oh so i guess you to spend some money https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/8808

Comment: or you can use open source free https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity

Comment: Which is better ? the one from assesstore or the one from github ?

Comment: @DennisLiu no idea you first try free github version