# Save character customization

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a question, on my game I can change the sprite of game objects and customize my character, but I have no idea how to save that.

Like, I wanted to create a list of characters that you saved, anyone who know how to do that?

(Im new in the programming world and english is not my main language)

Comment: Check this out: [link](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html). That is how you save it. To save it, I recommend making a new class that includes different values for you sprites such as the index of it or the colors you can set it to. Save the values of type of the script. Do you need more explanation?

Comment: [Best way to save data in Unity game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34426570/best-way-to-save-data-in-unity-game)

Answer (score 0):

At some point of your code this customization can be stored as series of numbers (maybe strings there is some kind of names), maybe those are floats storin position of different pasrts, but more likely which variant is being used as I assumed you achieved it by switching on and of various sprites. You can take those numbers and save them in one way or another for example  [to binary file](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/how-to-write-a-binary-file-in-C-Sharp/)

Answer (score -1):

you can use serialized obj and store your data on them then save them and when you need, load and create all objects again.