# How can I save player data in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a racing game. I have 10 cars and every car have attributes like speed, brake force, acceleration and handling. Player can upgrade cars with buttons. I have to save car upgrades and set the texts of buttons (like, Speed Level 1). I tried PlayerPrefs but I have so much data to save. My question is, which way I have to use for saving that data?

Comment: Your question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34426570/best-way-to-save-data-in-unity-game)

Answer (score 1):

Create a class

```
public class CarAttributes{
 private float speed;
 private int levelNumber;
}
```

Create a variable which will store all data of the car

```
CarAttributes car1 = new CarAttributes();
car1.speed = 100.0f;
car1.levelNumber = 3;
....
PlayerPrefs.SetString( "playerCar1", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(car1) );
```

To load data use

```
CarAttributes car1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CarAttributes>( PlayerPrefs.GetString( "playerCar1" ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no one single question for this, saving data in unity is just like saving data in every running program.
I'll try to enumerate some of the methods :

1. PlayerPrefs :
   As @KaushikChandru already answered you can use player prefs to save the data, just serialize them and save them as a String, and then you can deserialize them to get them back as objects.
2. File : Instead of using a PlayerPrefs you can use a File instead, here is a useful video that explains that ([here](http://youtube.com/watch?v=XOjd_qU2Ido) )
3. Use a database (sql lite) :
   The second one would be to use a database (local or remote). I suggest using SQL Lite, here is a useful tutorial for that ([here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8bpYHCKdZno))